# Is the argmax function locally continuous? And an implication..

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have deleted my old question and just focused on the core leaps of logic about which I am not completely sure. There are two core questions I have tried to ask as cleanly as possible. The best way to formalise these intuitions, if indeed they are correct, would be very helpful.

Suppose we are maximising a two dimensional function that also depends on some parameter $\alpha$.

$$\max_{x,y} f(x,y;\alpha) $$

1. Suppose that $(x^*(\alpha), y^*(\alpha))$ (henceforth $(x^*,y^*)$) globally maximises $f$ given $\alpha$, perhaps not uniquely. Now increase $\alpha$ very slightly to $\alpha'$. First I claim that while the original $(x^*,y^*)$  isn't necessarily ''near'' the global maximum of $f(\cdot,\cdot;\alpha')$, it is still near a local maximum. For a sufficiently small difference between $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ intuitively the old global maximum should still be a peak, perhaps shifted a bit, and perhaps not the global peak, but still a local peak and still nearby $(x^*,y^*)$. Is this correct?
2. Supposing the answer to 1 is yes, I know two more things. I know that 
   $$\frac{\partial x^*}{\partial\alpha } >0 \qquad \text{ and }\qquad \frac{\partial y^*}{\partial\alpha } >0. $$ That is, when we start at $(x^*,y^*)$ and then increase $\alpha$ very slightly, the new maximum moves 'up and right' of the old. Now denote the new maximum, as $(x' (\alpha'),y' (\alpha')) = (x',y'). $ I claim that $x'>x^*$ and $y'>y^*$. That is, knowing we are near a local maximum, and that from the old maximum the the maximum would move up and right is sufficient to conclude this.

Intuitively this all sounds OK to me. I am worried that this loose argument is missing something serious and technical. Help is much appreciated.